# How to find out which keys are involved in the join

Tags: python, pandas

df1 contains products characteristics in different columns. In the second dataframe, the characteristics of the products are located in one column. df2 are joined (left) to df1 using three keys as many times as there are columns of characteristics in the df1.
1.How to add a column to the second dataframe indicating whether the row is involved in the join?
2.How to make join more elegant))

```
d1 = {"Product": ["product1", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product3"], "Store": ["Store1", "Store2", "Store1", "Store1", "Store1", "Store2", "Store2"], "Attribute1": pd.Series(["red", "green", "green", "blue"], index=[0, 2, 5, 6]), "Attribute2": pd.Series(["red", "green", "red"], index=[1, 3, 4])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {"Product": ["product1", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product3", "product3", "product2"], "Store": ["Store1", "Store2", "Store1", "Store1", "Store1", "Store2", "Store2", "Store1", "Store2"], "Attribute": ["red", "red", "green", "green", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "red"], "Package": ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5", "type6", "type2", "type4", "type2"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute1'], right_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute'])
df3 = df3.drop(['Attribute'], axis=1)

df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2, how = 'left', left_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute2'], right_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute'])
df3 = df3.drop(['Attribute'], axis=1)

df3["Package"] = df3["Package_x"].map(str, na_action=None) + df3["Package_y"].map(str, na_action=None)
df3 = df3.drop(['Package_x'], axis=1)
df3 = df3.drop(['Package_y'], axis=1)
df3["Package"] = df3["Package"].str.replace("nan","")
```

Comment: Use `indicator` paramater of pd.DataFrame.merge.

Comment: Are attributes 1 and 2 mutually exclusive? When one is set the other is nan and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `indicator` parameter:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute1'], right_on = ['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute'], indicator=True)
df3 = df3.drop(['Attribute'], axis=1)
df3
```

Output:

```
    Product   Store Attribute1 Attribute2     _merge Package
0  product1  Store1        red        NaN       both   type1
1  product1  Store2        NaN        red  left_only   type2
2  product2  Store1      green        NaN       both   type3
3  product1  Store1        NaN      green  left_only   type4
4  product2  Store1        NaN        red  left_only   type5
5  product1  Store2      green        NaN       both   type6
6  product3  Store2       blue        NaN       both   type2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indicator is new parametr for me.

Comment: Is there any way to add indicator to second df? I need to now are excess row there not participating in join?

Comment: @AndreyNikitin  Use how='outer' with indicator to find all "joining" and "non-joining" rows in both dataframes. If you only concern you can use how='right' and you will see right_only in the indicator column.

Comment: In my case, the problem is that df1 consists of multiple columns participating in the join in different ways. If I heave "_merge" column in df1 (big database) it is difficult to find out are excess rows there in df2 (small dataframe whith only 3 collumns) to clean it. df2 is filled in manually and it would be convenient to have a status of participation in the join to clean out old unnecessary rows.

Answer (score 0):

If `Attribute1` and `Attribute2` columns are mutually exclusive, you can create a new column `Attribute` in df1 before merge:

```
out = (df1.assign(Attribute=df1['Attribute1'].fillna(df1['Attribute2']))
          .merge(df2, on=['Product', 'Store', 'Attribute'], how='left')
          .drop(columns='Attribute'))
print(out)

# Output
    Product   Store Attribute1 Attribute2 Package
0  product1  Store1        red        NaN   type1
1  product1  Store2        NaN        red   type2
2  product2  Store1      green        NaN   type3
3  product1  Store1        NaN      green   type4
4  product2  Store1        NaN        red   type5
5  product1  Store2      green        NaN   type6
6  product3  Store2       blue        NaN   type2
```

**Update**: if you have multiple `AttributeX` columns with a same prefix like "Attribute", you can replace:

```
df1['Attribute1'].fillna(df1['Attribute2'])
```

by:

```
df1.filter(like='Attribute').ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code is useful for me. But in this case i can not use united column because there are various unknown data in nan position in fact.